# How to POST an empty option in a form

Tags: html, forms

I have various form fields in my form however, they all require the user to be able to submit an empty value. The following always POST's the text from the first option.

How can I make it so that it POST's value=""

```html
<select class="form-control" name="type">
  <option value="" hidden>All</option>
  <option value="Apartment">Apartment</option>
  <option value="Villa">Villa</option>
  <option value="Hotel">Hotel</option>
</select>
```

if I dump $_POST['type'] I will get 'All' when the no option is selected. I need it empty.

UPDATE: Adding the PHP Function

```
/*****************
Setup the type filter
*****************************/
if (!$_POST['type'] == '') { 

  $type = $_POST['type']; 
  $type_query = array(       
    'meta_key'  =>  'type_name',
    'value'     =>  array($type)              
  );
  array_push($meta_query, $type_query);        
  $_SESSION['type'] = $type;

} elseif(isset($_SESSION['type'])) { 

  $type = $_SESSION['type']; 
  $type_query = array(       
    'meta_key'  =>  'type_name',
    'value'     =>  array($type)           
  );
  array_push($meta_query, $type_query);
}  



//POST dump

Array
(
    [type] => All
    [location] => All Locations
    [bedfrom] => 
    [bedto] => 
    [ref] => 
    [issearch] => 1
)

//SESSION dump

Array
(
    [location] => All Locations
    [type] => All
)
```

Comment: Why would you want to `POST` an empty value? If you dont need to `POST` anything to the server wouldnt a `GET` request work just fine?

Comment: https://i.imgur.com/j0tXV8X.png — I can't reproduce the problem.

Comment: And why not pass value="All" and then change the server script accordingly? - I don't even think you can have a hidden attribute on an option

Comment: Im posting the form values to another function which performs a get request on the DB.

Comment: Okay, sort of understand what you are saying from looking at the question again, you want to post no value if user selects all?

Comment: Exactly. My PHP on the other end checks to see if the value == ""

Comment: @AlexKnopp Can you post the function you are using to do this? Please also update the question to include the PHP tag. Sounds like the problem isnt your markup its in the PHP function you are using

Comment: that html template works just fine, what about the php code though ?

Comment: Will get it up asap.

Comment: @xanadev. Updated to include further information.

Comment: where you getting the name="type" in php ?? you are getting $_POST['location'] in php function .

Comment: can't see a `$_POST['type']` anywhere ?

Comment: i used a dummy php code to print the `$_POST['type']` and indeed it shows the value "" if All is selected.

Comment: Oops, sorry wrong filter code. Updated to show 'type' filter. POST and SESSION vars are shown below.

Comment: are you using ajax to send the form ?

Comment: Nope. Form is posted to a file (archive-properties.php). Oddly if i hard code value="foo" i get foo in the POST var.

Comment: just a tip `if (!$_POST['type'] == '')` could be written like so `if ( !empty($_POST['type']) )`

Answer (score 0):

```
<select class="form-control" name="type">
  <option value="" hidden>All</option>
  <option value="Apartment">Apartment</option>
  <option value="Villa">Villa</option>
  <option value="Hotel">Hotel</option>
</select>

if (isset($_POST['type']) ) { 
    $type = $_POST['type']; 
} elseif(isset($_SESSION['type'])) { 
     $type = $_SESSION['type']; 
}

$meta_query = [];
if(isset($type))//type == '' which means its set 
{
    $type_query = array(       
        'meta_key'  =>  'type_name',
        'value'     =>  array($type)              
    );
    array_push($meta_query, $type_query);
}
print_r($meta_query);
```

Comment: This still POST's as All when no option is selected.

Comment: output :  Array ( [0] => Array ( [meta_key] => type_name [value] => Array ( [0] => ) ) )

Comment: <form method="POST" action="backend.php">
<select class="form-control" name="type" >
    <option value="" hidden>All</option>    
    <option value="Apartment">Apartment</option>
    <option value="Villa">Villa</option>
    <option value="Hotel">Hotel</option>
  </select>
  <input type="submit" >
</form>

Comment: Array
(
    [type] => 
)

Comment: put a print_r($_POST)